# Javascript word count on page load not keyup

Tags: javascript, forms, pageload, onkeyup

I have a little bit of javascript that counts the amount of words on a box. The javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cnt(w,x){
        var y=w.value;
        var r = 0;
        a=y.replace(/\s/g,' ');
        a=a.split(' ');

        for (z=0; z<a.length; z++) {if (a[z].length > 0) r++;}
        x.value=r;
        if (r > 60) {
            x.value='Please reduce the word count'; 
        }
    } 
</script>
```

and the form like this:

```
<label>Free brochure from entry:</label>
<textarea name="freebrochureentryform" id="freebrochureentryform" onKeyUp="cnt(this,document.brochure.c)"><?php echo $row['freebrochureentryform']; ?></textarea>

<label>Brocure Entry Word Count:</label>
<input type="text" name="c" value="0" size="20" onKeyUp="cnt(document.brochure.freebrochureentryform,this)" />
```

Basically the bottom input field shows the amount of words in the upper one. But it only does so when you click on the upper box "freebrochureentryform", but i want it to load the amount of words as soon as the page loads not when you click the box. I guess it is to do with

```
onKeyUp="cnt(document.brochure.freebrochureentryform,this)"
```

But have no idea what to change it to.

(Btw way Brochure is the name of my form.)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `cnt()` function on `window.onload` event.

And instead of listening to `onkeyup` event, you can listen to the more appropriate `oninput` (or `onpropertychange` for IE) event:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bDng/1/)

```
<label>Free brochure from entry:</label>
<textarea name="freebrochureentryform" id="freebrochureentryform">Lorem Text</textarea>
<br />
<label>Brocure Entry Word Count:</label>
<input type="text" name="c" id="c" value="0" size="20" />
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
    function cnt(area,output){
        var txt=area.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").replace(/\s+/g," ").split(" ");
        if(txt.length>10){
            output.value="Please delete some word";
        }else{
            output.value=txt.length;
        }
    }
    var textarea=document.getElementById("freebrochureentryform");
    var info=document.getElementById("c");
    if("addEventListener" in window){
        if("oninput" in textarea){
            textarea.addEventListener("input",function(){
                cnt(textarea,info);
            },false);
        }else if("onpropertychange" in textarea){
            textarea.addEventListener("propertychange",function(e){
                if((e||event).propertyName=="value"){
                    cnt(textarea,info);
                }
            },false);
        }else{
            textarea.addEventListener("change",function(){
                cnt(textarea,info);
            },false);
        }
    }else{
        textarea.attachEvent("onpropertychange",function(){
            if(event.propertyName=="value"){
                cnt(textarea,info);
            }
        });
    }
    cnt(textarea,info);
};
```

Some instruction:

- `var txt=area.value`

  - `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")` means to `trim`;
  - `.replace(/\s+/g," ")` combines series of white spaces (including line feeds) into one (to better `split` without the need to iterate the splitted array);
  - `.split(" ")` split by white space (as you have already done).
- `oninput` is introduced in IE9 but [has some buggy behavior](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/05/12/fixing-oninput-in-ie9-using-html5widgets/), so you may want to try `onproperychange` first;
- putting `function cnt()` and `textarea`/`info` in `window.onload` makes them "safe" inside  the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). They can't pollute the global namespace, and things in global namespace can not pollute them.

Comment: That works great on page load, but i should have mention i also want it to update when you type on the box, so it shows as you type how many words you have typed so far.

Comment: @snookian That's what `oninput`/`onpropertychange` event listener is about. Do you have any problem when typing? I tested OK.

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyUp` triggers only on User Interaction.

If you load the side there is no Event `KeyUp`

so instead. Trigger it manually.

call `cnt(document.brochure.freebrochureentryform,document.brochure.c)` on your body manually (or `onload`)

Comment: but surly in wont know what ",this" is from the body tag?

Comment: yeah sorry just change `this` to your output `document.brochure.c`

Answer (score 0):

try to call `cnt(w,x)` on body `onload event`

Answer (score 0):

```
function countWords(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  let count = 0;
  if(arr.length > 0){
    for (let i = 0; i< arr.length - 1; i++){
        let sentence = arr[0];
        let bool = true;
        for(let j = 0; j < sentence.length - 1; j++){
            let charcode = arr[i].charCodeAt(j);
            if((charcode > 64 && charcode < 91) || (charcode > 96 && charcode < 123)){
            bool = false;
            }
        }
        if(bool == true){
        count += 1;
        }
    }
  }
  return arr.length - count;
}

//function calling
countWords("he is a good programer, he won 865 competitions, but sometimes he dont. 
what do you think? all test-cases should pass. done-done?");
```